Installed nvidia through file runner, nvcc is on my system but not properly configured
I installed version 11.8 of CUDA on my system through the runfile:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=runfile_local
It seems to have worked:
 ls /usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin
bin2c              cuobjdump                    __nvcc_device_query
computeprof        fatbinary                    nvcc.profile
compute-sanitizer  ncu                          nvdisasm
crt                ncu-ui                       nvlink
cudafe++           nsight_ee_plugins_manage.sh  nv-nsight-cu
cuda-gdb           nsight-sys                   nv-nsight-cu-cli
cuda-gdbserver     nsys                         nvprof
cuda-memcheck      nsys-exporter                nvprune
cuda-uninstaller   nsys-ui                      nvvp
cu++filt           nvcc                         ptxas

As nvcc is indeed under the binaries. However when I do nvcc --version I get that no such program is found (if I run it fromt he patch I get version 11.8 as expected).
Moreover, I am trying to get a pytorch program running under anaconda, and I get this message:
The detected CUDA version (11.8) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (10.2). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.

And when I run nvidia-smi I get:
NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4

So it seems I somehow have 3 different cuda versions atm? How can I reconcile everything to use the 11.8 version?

Did you change the environment vars PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the Nvidia instructions say? Include the /usr/local/cda.... /bin first in PATH and ..../lib64 first in LD_LIBRARY_PATH  The nvidia-smi output just shows up to what version is supported.

I realized that I had a typo on my bashrc edits which were meant to export the two paths, that was the issue
